# Styles of Bootstrap 3 are different from their own docs examples

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is how the styles of buttons in Bootstrap 3 look in Google Chrome on my own website, using the CDN or downloaded.

[image: Style of the links on my site]

And this is how they appear on the Bootstrap documentation site. I don't understand how do to get the new styles. Theirs have no gradient, just a solid flat theme.

[image: style of links on their site]

The same goes for most of the new Bootstrap 3 styles. I've checked the version on the css files etc, all 3.0.0.

How do I get the new styles?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be loading the theme.css file (or including theme.less somewhere). The theme.less file is optional, and makes Bootstrap 3 look more like Bootstrap 2.

Comment: D: So that's what "css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" does! A pity that's not really documented. Cheerz! :)